# Рамка с вырезом, но должно быть видно фоновое изображение

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не принципиально, на чистом css или при помощи каких-либо сторонних библиотек, нужно реализовать эту фичу. Знаю как делать cutout при помощи текста если у блока сплошной цвет фона, но не знаю как сделать это с background-image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу цель, то она вполне достижима. И для этого достаточно просто использовать элементы `fieldset` и `legend`.

Я не буду прикреплять фоновое изображение, так как боюсь нарушить авторские права, но в css-коде вы самостоятельно сможете вместо `background-color` указать `background-image` - результат будет тем же.

```css
.wrapper {
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.group {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 50px 100px;
}

.group legend {
    padding: 0 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <fieldset class="group">
        <legend>SERVICES</legend>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Возьмите за основу этот пример и поэкспериментируйте со стилями шрифтов и позиционированием элементов.

Удачи!